# process of making a CWMP (tr-069 protocol) to get info from devices

Tags: c#, soap, protocols

I'm trying to build c# software at my work that gets information from devices with tr-069(CWMP).
Could somebody tell me how to go further to build this?
Can also somebody tell me how to get soap message back from the CPE

I've already made this.
First function is only for the soap

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace SoapToClassData

{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Execute();
        }

        public static void Execute()
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = CreateWebRequest();
            XmlDocument soapEnvelopeXml = new XmlDocument();
            // soap 
            soapEnvelopeXml.LoadXml(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
                <SOAP-ENV:Envelope
                xmlns:SOAP-ENV=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/""
                xmlns:SOAP-ENC=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/""
                xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema""
                xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance""
                xmlns:cwmp=""urn:dslforum-org:cwmp-1-0"">
                <SOAP-ENV:Header>
                    <cwmp:ID SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand=""1"">279384</cwmp:ID>
                </SOAP-ENV:Header>
                <SOAP-ENV:Body>
                    <cwmp:Inform>
                        <DeviceId>
                            <Manufacturer>DrayTek Corp.</Manufacturer>
                            <OUI>00507F</OUI>
                            <ProductClass>EG8040H5</ProductClass>
                            <SerialNumber>001DAA18E148</SerialNumber>
                        </DeviceId>
                        <Event SOAP-ENC:arrayType=""cwmp: EventStruct[04]""> 
                            <EventStruct> 
                                <EventCode>0 BOOTSTRAP</EventCode> 
                                <CommandKey></CommandKey> 
                            </EventStruct> 
                            <EventStruct> 
                                <EventCode>1 BOOT</EventCode> 
                                <CommandKey></CommandKey> 
                            </EventStruct> 
                            <EventStruct> 
                                <EventCode>2 PERIODIC</EventCode> 
                                <CommandKey></CommandKey> 
                            </EventStruct>  
                            <EventStruct> 
                                <EventCode>4 VALUE CHANGE</EventCode> 
                                <CommandKey></CommandKey> 
                            </EventStruct> 
                        </Event>
                        <MaxEnvelopes>1</MaxEnvelopes>
                        <CurrentTime>2020-02-17T14:30:33+00:00</CurrentTime>
                        <RetryCount>0</RetryCount>
                        <ParameterList SOAP-ENC:arrayType=""cwmp:ParameterValueStruct[9]"">
                            <ParameterValueStruct>
                                <Name>InternetGatewayDevice.ManagementServer.ParameterKey</Name>
                                <Value xsi:type=""xsd:string""/>
                            </ParameterValueStruct>
                            <ParameterValueStruct>
                                <Name>InternetGatewayDevice.ManagementServer.ConnectionRequestURL</Name>
                                <Value xsi:type=""xsd:string"">http://ip:8069/cwm/CRN.html</Value>
                            </ParameterValueStruct>
                            <ParameterValueStruct>
                                <Name>InternetGatewayDevice.DeviceSummary</Name>
                                <Value xsi:type=""xsd:string"">InternetGatewayDevice:1.4[](Baseline:1, EthernetLAN:1, WiFiLAN:2, Time:1, IPPing:1, DeviceAssociation:1)</Value>
                            </ParameterValueStruct>
                            <ParameterValueStruct>
                                <Name>InternetGatewayDevice.DeviceInfo.SerialNumber</Name>
                                <Value xsi:type=""xsd:string"">001DAA18E148</Value>
                            </ParameterValueStruct>
                            <ParameterValueStruct>
                                <Name>InternetGatewayDevice.DeviceInfo.SpecVersion</Name>
                                <Value xsi:type=""xsd:string"">1.0</Value>
                            </ParameterValueStruct>
                            <ParameterValueStruct>
                                <Name>InternetGatewayDevice.DeviceInfo.HardwareVersion</Name>
                                <Value xsi:type=""xsd:string"">e</Value>
                            </ParameterValueStruct>
                            <ParameterValueStruct>
                                <Name>InternetGatewayDevice.DeviceInfo.SoftwareVersion</Name>
                                <Value xsi:type=""xsd:string"">3.9.1.1</Value>
                            </ParameterValueStruct>
                            <ParameterValueStruct>
                                <Name>InternetGatewayDevice.DeviceInfo.ProvisioningCode</Name>
                                <Value xsi:type=""xsd:string""/>
                            </ParameterValueStruct>
                            <ParameterValueStruct>
                                <Name>InternetGatewayDevice.WANDevice.1.WANConnectionDevice.1.WANIPConnection.1.ExternalIPAddress</Name>
                                <Value xsi:type=""xsd:string"">213.125.61.108</Value>
                            </ParameterValueStruct>
                        </ParameterList>
                    </cwmp:Inform>
                    <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
                        <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Client</faultcode>
                        <faultstring>CWMP fault</faultstring>
                        <detail>
                            <cwmp:fault>
                                <FaultCode>9005</FaultCode>
                                <FaultString>Invalid parameter Name</FaultString>
                            </cwmp:fault>
                        </detail>
                    </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
                </SOAP-ENV:Body>
            </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>");

            using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                soapEnvelopeXml.Save(stream);
            }

            using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    string soapResult = rd.ReadToEnd();
                    // I get here the soap that i've typed here above
                    Console.WriteLine(soapResult);
                }
            }
        }
```

Here I make connection with the acs and send the soap

```
        // connection with the acs
        public static HttpWebRequest CreateWebRequest()
        {
            string action = "https://acsnoc.hompes.nl:443/ACSServer/services/ACSServlet";

            HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"https://acsnoc.hompes.nl:443/ACSServer/services/ACSServlet");
            webRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
            webRequest.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", action);
            webRequest.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
            webRequest.Accept = "text/xml";
            webRequest.Method = "POST";
            return webRequest;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need understand the protocol better, I recommend spending some time here https://www.qacafe.com/tr-069-training/session-overview/, they have great material on the topic.

As for your code goes ... as you'll understand after watching the training, if you want to talk to the CPE ... you can't ... not directly.

The protocol is a little backwards so to say. The communication is **always** CPE initiated. You want to talk to the CPE, with the right credentials, you do a "Connection Request", which only an HTTP GET request. You could see this as a "poke" ... *"hey, I need to talk to you"*. But, it will not talk to "you", it will talk to the configured ACS.

The communication starts with the CPE sending an "Inform", which is basically something like that chunk of XML you have there, sent as a SOAP request.
After a few "heanshake-like" responses and requests, the CPE will send and "empty POST" (a POST request without any payload ... besides the headers). This is telling the ACS "I'm waiting for instructions".

Again, as said before, the protocol is a little backwards and here's what I meant by that...
The "requests" from the ACS (be it for reading or setting information) they go to CPE, one by one, in the body of the HTTP responses, beginning with that first Empty POST. Then the CPE responds with the data of the first request with another POST, the ACS sends the next "request" in the HTTP response ... and so on.

When the ACS has nothing else to say, it will respond, to this last POST he received, with an `HTTP 204 No Content, telling this way to the CPE "I have nothing else to say", so the CPE closes the HTTP session.
[image]
The red arrows are the HTTP POST requests sent from the CPE.
The green arrows are the HTTP responses to those request.